# Express does not see URL parameters

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mean-stack

I am writing a NodeJS server with REST Api using Express. I have Users model and methods to fetch all the users:

```
  app.get('/api/users', function(req, res){

  User.find(function(err, users){
    if(err){ return err; }
    res.json(users);
  });
});
```

and a method to get a user by ID:

```
app.get('api/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("one");
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
    res.send(err);
    res.json(user);
  });
});
```

But when I try to send a URL parameter to get a user by ID the relevant method is not called. And `req.params` is `{}`.

Postman shows this:
[image]

I am new to the MEAN stack so I may have overlooked some obvious mistakes. But what can be the reason for that?

EDIT:

It was a typo, I just forgot a slash

Comment: Does your get api/users route work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it like

```
app.get('/api/users/:id',....
```

you forget starting slash (/)

Comment: sure, 10 mins should pass